# create hierachical dynamic JS object

Tags: javascript

My problem is that I want to build a JS object message hierarchical dynamic and this without array. I've searched a lot on stackoverflow, google and many other sites, but unfortunately have not found a solution and I am fairly new to this area.
There are many examples with array, but they didn't answer my question.
This is my structure.

```
{
"ID" : 1,
"SRC" : "SYS",
"LOG" : {
    "PARAM" : {
        "NUM" : 3,
        "N01" : {
            " TO " : 1,
            " OM " : 1,
            " NO " : 1,
            " IO " : 1,
        },
        "N02" : {
            " TO " : 2,
            " OM " : 2,
            " NO " : 2,
            " IO " : 2,
        },
        "N03" : {
            " TO " : 3,
            " OM " : 3,
            " NO " : 3,
            " IO " : 3,
        }
    }
}}
```

If only N02 exists next time, the structure should look like this. And so on...

```
{
"ID" : 1,
"SRC" : "SYS",
"LOG" : {
    "PARAM" : {
        "NUM" : 1,
        "N02" : {
            " TO " : 2,
            " OM " : 2,
            " NO " : 2,
            " IO " : 2,
        }}}}
```

From NUM in the presence of, for example, N01 should be added into the structure. And if N01 does not exist and N02 is available, so N02 needs to be added in the hierarchical structure.
I need some help to do this in JavaScript.

Comment: Does the object have to have a key? I mean, instead of using `N01` to `N03` you could just use an array: `PARAM: [ {}, {}, {} ]`.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: yes, this is my structure, and the main problem is, how to implement this structure in javascript without array? is that even possible? or i should do it in array?

Comment: if my answer was helpfull please vote it @goldstone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not shure if i understand your question correct but i would create a basic object like

```js
message = {
            addParam: function (item) {
                var paramLength = 0;
                for (var k in this.LOG.PARAM) {
                    if (this.LOG.PARAM.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                        paramLength++;
                    }
                }
                this.LOG.PARAM["NUM"] = paramLength;
                this.LOG.PARAM["N"+paramLength] = item;
            },
            ID: 1,
            SRC: "SYS",
            LOG: {
                PARAM: {
                    NUM: 0,
                }
            }
        }
        message.addParam({
            " TO ": 1,
            " OM ": 1,
            " NO ": 1,
            " IO ": 1,
        });
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(message, null, 4);
```

```html
<div ><pre id="output"></pre></div>
```

All properties can be modified easely just select it like `message.ID` an add a value like `message.ID = 12`.

I also added a function to this object 'addParam'. This will add the additional objects to the PARAM property an will update the number value.

Comment: I'd enjoy doing it, but I cant because I stil dont have 15 reputation...or when you know how, please let me know. :)